# Type conversion using numeric_std

Tags: type-conversion, vhdl

I'm in the process of converting a few VHDL files over to numberic_std after using std_logic_unsigned. A few of lines are given me grief. For example, I have following code fragment that does not want to convert properly:

```
elsif (reg(7) = '0' and reg(2 downto 0) > PKG_VAR) then
```

I've tried various conversion attempts, but no such luck:

```
elsif (unsigned(reg(7) = '0' and unsigned(reg(2 downto 0)) > unsigned(PKG_VAR)

elsif (resize(unsigned(reg(7),3) = '0' and unsigned(reg(2 downto 0)) > unsigned(PKG_VAR)
```

Does anyone have any ideas how this can be converted following the VHDL LRM? I'm using VHDL 2002.

Comment: Add the declarations of `reg` and `PKG_VAR` so we can see what types they are! `reg(7)` is probably a std_logic and it won't need any type conversion

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about not supplying the definition of the signals and constant! Both reg and PKG_VAR are std_logic types.

I believe I have found a solution to my dilemma. When using numeric_std, change the line to read as follows:

```
elsif (reg(7) = '0' and unsigned(reg(2 downto 0)) > unsigned(PKG_VAR)) then
```

I've found that Cadence Incisive compiles this line without errors or warnings, and code simulates as expected.

I have not synthesized this code and run through Formality, but I believe this is the correct solution.